# MVC contextual "help" framework for site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Sorry for the bad title. Not sure how to title this.

I have a web site going to be public facing, all throughout the site, I want to add "Help" icons and when the user clicks them, it will show contextual help for the page they are on. Using MVC, DRY and good design principles, does anyone have any ideas (at a high level) how to do this?

Comment: This is a ginormous question. Perhaps try something, break down your problems into discrete chunks, and ask questions about those chunks?

Comment: So, did you ever get this issue resolved? Enquiring minds, etc.

Comment: No not yet, i've been putting it off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm partial to qtip (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) as a means of displaying these hints. As far as a specific implementation of the content of these help tips, well, they're contextual. You can have some sort of help term repository, or just hard-code the help contents if you do not foresee a need to translate into different languages or reuse the help contents.

Comment: broken link leads to "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: This answer is pretty obsolete 11 years later.